# Type error : importing things and doesn't work

Tags: python-2.7, easygui

Guys can you help please?
You see I created a module (if you want to know how get Hello world book 2nd edition) and imported it but the functions don't work. Here are the module and scripts

### coin.py

```
class Coin:
    def flip_coin(self, op):
        a = random.choice(op)
        easygui.msgbox(a)
```

### script

```
import random
import easygui
from coin import Coin

op = ["Heads", "Tails"]

easygui.msgbox("Ready?")
Coin.flip_coin()
```

You guys wanted to see the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python27\Hello world\coin", line 9, in <module> flip_coin() TypeError: flip_coin() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
```

Comment: Please don't just say "it doesn't work". Surely there's an error message and a traceback of some sort.

Comment: Sanity check: are `coin.py` and `script` in the same folder? They have to be without further finagling.

Comment: @kamses  Yeah they are.

Comment: @AKX here : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Hello world\flippingcoin", line 8, in <module>
    Coin.flip_coin()
TypeError: unbound method flip_coin() must be called with Coin instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is (aside from the fact that your question doesn't have the actual error ;-) ) that you haven't instantiated an object of your `Coin` class, and you don't pass in `op`.

In addition, since `Coin` lives in a separate module, it too needs to have `random` and `easygui` imported if you use them.

### coin.py

```
import random
import easygui


class Coin:
    def flip_coin(self, op):
        a = random.choice(op)
        easygui.msgbox(a)
```

### script

```
import easygui
from coin import Coin

coin = Coin()  # instantiate the class

easygui.msgbox("Ready?")
coin.flip_coin(["Heads", "Tails"])
```

---

However, it's not Pythonic to use a class when you don't actually need to store state.

Instead, you can just leave `def flip_coin(op):` a free function -- and also, since coins don't usually have more options than heads or tails:

```
import random
import easygui

def flip_coin():
    a = random.choice(["Heads", "Tails"])
    easygui.msgbox(a) 

easygui.msgbox("Ready?")
flip_coin()
```

Comment: I got an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Hello world\coin", line 9, in <module>
    flip_coin()
TypeError: flip_coin() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)`